# How to select multiple files from different folders?

Tags: java, android, sharing

I am writing an android ftp server app and i need to select multiple files...i used the Intent.putExtra() method with EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE and it is working fine...But i need to select multiple files from different folders..Like, i want to choose 2 files from dir1 and 3 from dir2... It isn't allowed..i can choose multiple files from a single folder but not multiple folders...How can i solve this?
This is my code:

```
Intent filechooser= new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
 filechooser.setType("*/*");
    filechooser.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    filechooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(filechooser, 10);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("err",e.getMessage());
    }
```

Any and all comments and answers are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for that — or, more accurately, the behavior of the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` UI and whether it allows what you want is up to Android, and stock Android does not support this.

In your own UI, you can allow the user to execute that code snippet several times, where you build up the roster of files from multiple responses.